# Integrating tweet button

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to integrate tweet button to my site. My page url ends with a "~" sign, but the url that twitter generates after shortening redirects to a page without this tilda sign at the end.

I think due to this the tweet count is not going up. Is there a way to correct this or may be, prevent the url from being shortened?

Comment: What is the significance of the '~'? If it's possible, the simplest solution seems to be to get rid of the tilde

Comment: '~' was actually used as a part of url rewriting. So it seems that that fault was on our side. Getting rid of '~' is the solution. Thanks